# Why this print only 0,1,2

Tags: php, for-loop

This nested for loops without curly brackets print only 0,1,2...
When echo out the output of the first for loop it keeps running until 2.but final output is 0,1,2.. why is that?

```
<?php 

    for($x = 0; $x<3; $x++) 
        for($x = 0; $x<3; $x++)
            echo $x;

?>
```

Comment: what your expected output?

Comment: in inner loop you use same var $x its create problem

Comment: after execution first time inner loop $x val is 3.so first loop's  condition is going false. and stop execution.

Comment: No.its only print 0,1,2.. I thought it should print  0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2.but only prints 0,1,2..i think it cause with curly braces

Comment: when i echo out the first for loop output its run until 2.

Comment: no there is no problem due to braces. see dhruv's answer

Comment: And hint: the **real** take away here is: do **not** write such code.

Comment: The problem is because of using $x in both places and the ```0,1,2``` that you are getting is because of second loop. Once the second loop completed the $x value will be 3 and then the first loop will be not iterated anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**For desired output 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2**

**change second for loop variable**

**because having same variable ,it neglects the execution of outer loop**

```
for($x = 0; $x<3; $x++) 
        for($y = 0; $y<3; $y++)
            echo $y;
```

Comment: what do mean by `it neglects the execution of inner loop` ?

Comment: when i run this code `for($x = 0; $x<3;$x++)
    echo 'first'.$x.'<br>';
    for($x = 0; $x<3;$x++)
        echo 'second'.$x.'<br>';`  it gives me first0
first1
first2
second0
second1
second2

Comment: having same variable name u can only execute inner loop from nested for loop

Answer (score 0):

As you asked :

> Why this print only 0,1,2

```
for($x = 0; $x<3; $x++) //2nd time when it check the condition $x become 3; 3<3 fails
    for($x = 0; $x<3; $x++)//After this loop value of $x becomes 3
        echo $x; //
```

Because after inner loop value of `$x` becomes 3 and fails for outer loop also as you took same variable name,

You can check here : https://eval.in/705347

Comment: Yeah.but when i remove the brackets outer for loop execute until 2

Comment: dear, only one line will execute if you don't put brackets. means the first loop will no longer be as outer loop it will be separate loop.